# SQL запрос Выдать номера деталей, поставляемых более чем одним поставщиком

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравсвуйте.Такая проблема
Выдать номера деталей, поставляемых более чем одним поставщиком.
У меня есть такой запрос. Но мне сказали сделать нужно через подзапрос.
Таблицы: SP - поставки, S - поставщики, P - детали

```
select 
  n_det 
from SP
group by n_det 
having count(n_post) > 1
```

[image: SP]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ууу... учебные задания у нас тут за Вас никто решать не станет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашу поддержку скажу, что на вопрос вы ответили и составили запрос правильно. Корректнее было бы просить вывести имя детали.

Для решения задачи можно воспользоваться оператором `EXISTS`, который принимает значение `TRUE`, если подзапрос содержит любое количество строк, иначе его значение равно `FALSE`. Для `NOT EXISTS` все наоборот.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM p
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT
     n_det 
   FROM SP
   WHERE sp.n_det = p.n_det 
   GROUP BY sp.n_det
   HAVING count(sp.n_post) > 1)
```

В подзапросе можно опустить `GROUP BY`, т.к. все строки по условию будут иметь одинаковый номер детали для каждой детали главного запроса.

Другой вариант

```
SELECT
  *
FROM p
WHERE 
  (SELECT
     count(sp.n_post) 
   FROM SP
   WHERE sp.n_det = p.n_det) > 1
```

Третий вариант с полностью вашим запросом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM p
where p.n_det in 
(select 
   n_det 
 from SP
 group by n_det 
 having count(n_post) > 1)
```

Comment: Уже сам разобрался, но все равно спасибо, для понимания полезно будет.